# Convert large xml values into double type json?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm forming an xml whose snippet is -

```
<cache-properties>
  <list-cache-hit-rate>
    <units>hits/sec</units>
    <value>1.5308452E6</value>
  </list-cache-hit-rate>
  <list-cache-miss-rate>
    <units>misses/sec</units>
    <value>25422.167</value>
  </list-cache-miss-rate>
  <compressed-tree-cache-hit-rate>
    <units>hits/sec</units>
    <value>970.2339</value>
```

Notice the value `1.5308452E6` is big enough that the values are stored as exponent while performing `fn:sum()` behind the scene.
Later, I'm converting the xml to json by the following function -

```
let $arr := json:to-array(local:tojson($data))
return (($data))
```

and value converted looks like this -

```
cache-properties": {
  "list-cache-hit-rate": {
    "units": "hits/sec", 
    "value": 1.5308452E6
  }, 
  "list-cache-miss-rate": {
    "units": "misses/sec", 
    "value": "25422.167"
  }, 
  "compressed-tree-cache-hit-rate": {
    "units": "hits/sec", 
    "value": "970.2339"
  },
```

Notice the values are enclosed in quotes except `1.5308452E6` this value. This is not in quotes. What correction is needed here ? Or is this correct? I'd rather have all values in quotes. This is my custom transform function-

```
declare function local:tojson($func){
let $custom := let $config := json:config("custom")
                let $_ := map:put( $config, "whitespace", "ignore" )
                let $_ := map:put( $config, "array-element-names", "Video" )
                return $config
return json:transform-to-json($func,$custom)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the xml schema.  Your snippets appear to be similar or identical to marklogic system status xml schema however you mention 'fn:sum in the background' so Im guessing you have applied a transformation which has changed the xsd type.
The json transformation code uses the XSD type if in scope to determine the typed output in JSON (for XML numeric types).  Also if the number is 'too large' it can convert to string to avoid JavaScript issue.
( it basically uses fn:data(value) to convert )

If needed you can either force a string type onto your xml, or you can specialize the transformation by overriding one of the json-custom: primitives in json/custom.xqy by supplying the appropriate mapping in the config.  Look into the source for the full list of overridable functions.   They are not fully documented as they are not with full generality in mind and may not be obvious, easy or possibly to change behaviour in every conceivable way.

The strategies are to either
Use an XML with schema in scope that types atomic values explicitly (in your case as xs:string),
Override one of the low level functions in custom.xqy
Convert the JSON by post-processing and 'stringify' the desired elements
Roll your own (not too difficult with the samples show)
All of the above